# How can I solve error 5 from WriteProcessMemory?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am requesting SE_DEBUG_NAME, and I am still unable to use WriteProcessMemory() to write to lsass.exe.
I am running my program as an administrator (changed the manifest to "requireAdministrator"). I have tried my program and it does write to svchost.exe, explorer.exe, and chrome.exe, but just not lsass.exe.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream> 


BOOL SetPrivilege(
    HANDLE hToken,          // access token handle
    LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege,  // name of privilege to enable/disable
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege   // to enable or disable privilege
)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(
        NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
        lpszPrivilege,   // privilege to lookup 
        &luid))        // receives LUID of privilege
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege)
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    // Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hToken,
        FALSE,
        &tp,
        sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
        (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,
        (PDWORD)NULL))
    {
        printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)

    {
        printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
void write()
{
    std::string writing = "lmaoxd";
    auto writing_size = sizeof(writing);

    DWORD pID = 696;
    HANDLE hToken;

    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
    SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE);
    CloseHandle(hToken);

    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
    WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)0x1d72000391e, &writing, writing_size, 0);
    CloseHandle(pHandle);

    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    std::cout << "Error: " << error << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    write();
    system("pause");
}
```

What can I do to solve error 5?

Comment: You honestly think Windows is going to provide a simple, easy, direct way to modify the memory of the local security authentication server? Windows may not be the most secure OS in history, but it's still not going to make *that* task particularly easy.

Comment: Complete absence of error reporting can't help

Comment: before solve error need check are error at all exist. you not check any api call result. so you even can not know was error or no

Comment: Mucking with other process's memory is an advanced, I'd call it very advanced, programming skill. If you don't already have a solid understanding of Windows's dark underbelly and the tricks used to prevent snooping, you are in for a rough ride. This isn't something you can [cargo-cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) your way through.

Answer (score 1):

Lsass is protected, it's not an Admin process, but a system process. Writing to it should only (if at all) be possible from another system process. Check SysInternals psexec to start your process as system, If really needed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

Comment: no, lsass.exe not protected process and if you have debug privilege possible open it with all access

Comment: @epiic - why you decide that error from `WriteProcessMemory` ?

Comment: I used GetLastError() right after WriteProcessMemory()

Comment: no, you used `GetLastError` wrong. you not check any system call result, except not your code which you found and copy-paste

Comment: @epiic no, are you not. For starters, you are calling it after `CloseHandle()`, which can affect its value. But also, calling it after `WriteProcessMemory()` is meaningful ONLY if `WriteProcessMemory()` actually fails, which you are not checking for. You MUST check the return value of each API function, and then call `GetLastError()` *immediately* ONLY if it is meaningful to do so.  Otherwise, you are picking up an error code from an earlier API call that may not have anything to do with what you are doing.

Comment: yes even when i use ```GetLastError()``` after ```WriteProcessMemory()```it still returns error 5.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following code to get the base address and use [VirtualProtectEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex) to change the page protection on the memory block.

Code Sample: (It works for me)

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>

DWORD_PTR GetProcessBaseAddress(DWORD processID)
{
    DWORD_PTR   baseAddress = 0;
    HANDLE      processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
    HMODULE* moduleArray;
    LPBYTE      moduleArrayBytes;
    DWORD       bytesRequired;

    if (processHandle)
    {
        if (EnumProcessModules(processHandle, NULL, 0, &bytesRequired))
        {
            if (bytesRequired)
            {
                moduleArrayBytes = (LPBYTE)LocalAlloc(LPTR, bytesRequired);

                if (moduleArrayBytes)
                {
                    unsigned int moduleCount;

                    moduleCount = bytesRequired / sizeof(HMODULE);
                    moduleArray = (HMODULE*)moduleArrayBytes;

                    if (EnumProcessModules(processHandle, moduleArray, bytesRequired, &bytesRequired))
                    {
                        baseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)moduleArray[0];
                    }

                    LocalFree(moduleArrayBytes);
                }
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(processHandle);
    }

    return baseAddress;
}

BOOL SetPrivilege(
    HANDLE hToken,          // access token handle
    LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege,  // name of privilege to enable/disable
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege   // to enable or disable privilege
)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(
        NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
        lpszPrivilege,   // privilege to lookup 
        &luid))        // receives LUID of privilege
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege)
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    // Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hToken,
        FALSE,
        &tp,
        sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
        (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,
        (PDWORD)NULL))
    {
        printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)

    {
        printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
void write()
{
    char writing[] = "lmaoxd";
    int writing_size = sizeof(writing);

    DWORD pID = 1092;  //pid of lsass.exe
    HANDLE hToken;

    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
    SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE);
    CloseHandle(hToken);

    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);

    DWORD h =  GetProcessBaseAddress(pID);
    SetLastError(0);
    DWORD oldProtect;
    BOOL ret = VirtualProtectEx(pHandle, (LPVOID)h, writing_size, PAGE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    SetLastError(0);
    ret = WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)h, writing, writing_size, 0);
    error = GetLastError();
    std::cout << "Error: " << error << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(pHandle);


}

int main()
{
    write();
    system("pause");
}
```

Note: Make sure that VS TOOL is running as an administrator and debug with x64.

Comment: @epiic Hi, please tell me if the answer is useful to you?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see this message. It appears that the program returns error 998.

Comment: Please read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599629/still-get-error-5-from-writeprocessmemory#comment108963241_61599629).

Comment: @IInspectable I have read the comments and I have corrected some errors. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @epiic I noticed that you tried to pass another base address of lsass.exe to `WriteProcessMemory`, which is why you get error 5. In my code, `GetProcessBaseAddress` has returned the base address for you, please use this base address for testing. You only need to add the pid of lsass.exe.

Comment: There's still so much wrong with this code. For example, why are there calls to `LocalAlloc`/`LocalFree` instead of using, say, a C++ `vector`? Why is there `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` in the call to `OpenProcess`, when all you need is enumerate the process' modules? Why does the call to `GetLastError` not evaluate, whether it will return a meaningful value?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT, now I'm getting error 998 (no access)... while running as an administrator...

Comment: @epiic Have you checked the return value of each function? Such as `VirtualProtectEx`, `WriteProcessMemory`